# BroadcastReceiver on Android P

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-9.0-pie

Since Android 9 is online and I am having a troubles to send a notification with my JobIntentService, which launched using the BroadcastReceiver .

It works great on other devices with Android <= 8.1 and I can get the notification in no time .
Sometimes It works on Android P too, but sometimes the System doesn't fire the registered services with the AlarmManager ! OR I am not able to receive it.

What is going wrong ? 
AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            onBoot(context);
        }
        Log.d("action", "i recieved an action");

        try {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String message = bundle.getString("Push_Message", "No Content");
            int type = bundle.getInt("Push_Type", -1);

            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AppJobService.class);
            newIntent.putExtra("Push_Message", message);
            newIntent.putExtra("Push_Type", type);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            AppJobService.enqueueWork(context, AppJobService.class, AppJobService.JOB_ID, newIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Here I've added the Receiver to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".notifications.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And I am registering the Service with the AlarmManager in this way inside a class, that inherits from JobIntentService

AppJobService.java

```
    public void sendTimedNotification(String message, int type, long timeInMillis) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("Push_Message", message);
        intent.putExtra("Push_Type", type);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, sender);

    }
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @aminpinjari yes, push notification from firebase or other services. Android system is very strict about battery usage since android P .

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue as my broadcast receiver is not triggered , did you find any solution for this , thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Per Document:

> Alarms do not fire when the device is idle in Doze mode. Any scheduled
>   alarms will be deferred until the device exits Doze. If you need to
>   ensure that your work completes even when the device is idle there are
>   several options available. You can use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or
>   setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() to guarantee that the alarms will execute.
>   Another option is to use the new WorkManager API, which is built to
>   perform background work either once or periodically. For more
>   information, see Schedule tasks with WorkManager.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms